# Currently, does substrate/polkadot make use of PrimaryProposal stage?

Tags: grandpa

While observing the GRANDPA communication between 2 Substrates nodes and 1 [Gossamer](https://github.com/ChainSafe/gossamer) node I notice that only [`Prevotes`](https://crates.parity.io/sc_finality_grandpa/type.Prevote.html) and [`Precommmits`](https://crates.parity.io/sc_finality_grandpa/type.Precommit.html) were being exchanged. Currently, are the [`PrimaryProposal`](https://crates.parity.io/sc_finality_grandpa/type.PrimaryPropose.html) messages not in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are in use, but they are sort of plan B to ensure liveness (that is to make sure the best final candidate of round r-1 is finalized before we move to round r+1). So you should not expect to see them often when the network consists of few well-connected honest nodes (so for example, Aura-BABE does not fork due two nodes winning the same BABE slot and half of the network sees one candidate first and the other half see the other).

Specifically, see [Algorithm 14. Play-Grandpa-Round](https://spec.polkadot.network/#_voting_process_in_round_r) line 4. The primary only makes a proposal if it sees (based on the votes it has observed) the best final candidate of round r-1 failed to be finalized in that round. If it observes that the best final candidate of last round (r-1) or any of its descendants has been finalized in that round, then it does not send the primary proposal in the current round (r).

See [this example](https://spec.polkadot.network/#exmp-candid-unfinalized) of a situtaion when the network fails to finalize the best candidate.